# delete operator with var and non var variables

Tags: javascript

I tried delete a variable in javascript using delete operator, but found some issue.
Can you guys please explain the below code, and why it is happening

```
>> var a = 5;

>> delete a
false

>>a
5

>> b=5;

>>delete b
true

>>b
ReferenceError b is not defined
```

why var a = 5 and b = 5 are different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a variable is created using a variable declaration (i.e. using *var*) then it is created with its deleteable flag set to *false*.

When a variable is created implicitly by assignment without being declared, its deleteable flag is set to *true*.

It is a peculiarity of the global execution context that variables are also made properties of the global object (this doesn't happen in function or eval code). So when you do:

```
var a;
```

Then *a* is a variable and also a property of the global (window in a browser) object and has its deleteable flag set to *false*. But:

```
a = 'foo';
```

creates *a* as a global variable without a declaration, so its deleteable flag is set to *true*.

The result is that you can delete global variables created implicitly, but not those created by declarations (including function declarations).

Answer (score 6):

Without using `var`, assignment with the `=` operator is always assigning a property, in your second case the object is implicitly the global object (`window` in your browser).

The `delete` operator is *only* for deleting properties on objects, not normal variables.

Comment: +1 In case the OP is wondering how it's assigning a property in the case of `b`, it's assigning it to the `window` object. After calling `delete` on it, the property will be gone from the `window` object.

Comment: Very confusing answer. The simple answer is that global variables created with *var* have their *deleteable* flag set to false, whereas those created without *var* (i.e. by simple assignment) have their *deleteable* flat set to true.

Comment: @RobG I'll make an edit to make it (hopefully) less confusing.

Comment: Hi alex, I have doubt, when I define var a = 5;
and I check
>>window.a
5
then a is property of window object, then why the definition of delete operator, i.e., it delete object property ; does not work.

Comment: @jforjs The way I understood it years ago seems like it can be understood much clearer now. Check out [RobG's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22317789/31671) (and you should probably accept his too).

Answer (score 3):

The delete operator deletes an object, an object's property, or an element from an array. The operator can also delete variables which are not declared with the var statement.

```
delete objectName.property 
delete objectName[index]
```

Comment: Note: you *shouldn't* be using `delete` to remove array members.

Comment: yes...but i just wanted to let others know that we can use delete to remove array members...because it will remove only members but will not change the length

Answer (score 1):

The **[delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)** operator removes a property from an object not the normal variables. Here in this case the object is global implicitly.

**On a side note:-**

When you write `var x = 5` then it declares variable x in current scope ie, in execution context. If declaration appears in a function then local variable is declared and if it's in global scope then global variable is declared.

Whereas when you say `x = 5`,then it is merely a property assignment. It first tries to resolve x against scope chain. If it finds `x` anywhere in that scope chain then it performs assignment otherwise it creates `x` property on a global object.